# Python + Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Does anyone know how to install selenium in python?

Yes, I use windows. My python is 2.7

So I tried using this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

But the question is: where I run the "pip install-U command selenium"?

Comment: just copy the folder to c:\python27\Lib

Comment: Yes, someone knows.  Do you have a more specific question?  What OS?  What version of Python? which Selenium Webdriver?  What errors are you encountering?

Comment: Yes, I use windows. My python is 2.7

So I tried using this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

But the question is: where I run the "pip install-U command selenium"?

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install -U selenium
```

after

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
```

Simple example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
assert "Yahoo!" in browser.title
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("seleniumhq" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

Comment: You can also just download Selenium manually (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and then add the selenium folder (`selenium-2.31.0/py/selenium/`) inside your project. This way it's easier to distribute and will not be dependent on using the `pip` first on other people's machines :)

Comment: Until then I have just the python installed (http://www.python.org/download/)

SO: Windows